# code needs to loop over minimum 2000 times in php foreach

Tags: php, symfony, foreach

I am having the foreach loop that will run minimum 2000 loops

```
foreach ($giftCardSchemeData as $keypreload => $preload) {
    for ($i=0; $i <$preload['quantity'] ; $i++) {
      $cardid = new CarddetailsId($uuidGenerator->generate());
      $cardnumber = self::getCardNumber();
      $cardexistencetype = ($key == "giftCardSchemeData") ? "Physical" : "E-Card" ;
      $giftCardSchemeDataDb = array('preload' => array('value' => $preload['value'], 'expirymonths' => $preload['expiryMonths']));
      $otherdata = array('cardnumber' => $cardnumber, 'cardexistencetype' => $cardexistencetype, 'isgiftcard' => true , 'giftcardamount' => $preload['value'],'giftCardSchemeData' => json_encode($giftCardSchemeDataDb), 'expirymonths' => $preload['expiryMonths'], 'isloyaltycard' => false, 'loyaltypoints' => null,'loyaltyCardSchemeData' => null, 'loyaltyRedeemAmount' => null, 'pinnumber' => mt_rand(100000,999999));
      $output = array_merge($data, $otherdata);
      // var_dump($output);
      $carddetailsRepository = $this->get('oloy.carddetails.repository');
      $carddetails = $carddetailsRepository->findByCardnumber($cardnumber);
        if (!$carddetails) {
          $commandBus->dispatch(
              new CreateCarddetails($cardid, $output)
          );
        } else {
          self::generateCardFunctionForErrorException($cardid, $output, $commandBus);
        }
    }
}
```

Like above foreach I am having totally 5 of them. When I call the function each time the 5 foreach runs and then return the response. It take more time and the php maximum execution time occurs.
Is there a any way to send the response and then we could run the foreach in server side and not creating the maximum execution time issue.Also need an optimization for the foreach.

---

Also In symfony I have tried the try catch method for the existence check in the above code it return the Entity closed Error. I have teprorily used the existence check in Db but need an optimization

Comment: What is the context of this? Is it something you do once or rarely to generate new cards, or is it something you do for every visitor to your site?

Comment: have you tried ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); set_time_limit(0);

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lot wrong (or to be optimized) with this code, but let's focus on your questions:

First I think this code shouldn't be in code that will be triggered by a visitor.
You should seperate 2 processes:
1. A cronjob that runs that will generate everything that must be generated and saved that generated info to a database. The cronjob can take as much time as it needs. Look at [Symfony's console components](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console)
2. A page that displays only the generated info by fetching it from the database and passing it to a Twig template.

However, looking at the code you posted I think it can be greatly optimized as is. You seem to have a foreach loop that fetches variable data, and in that you have a for-loop that does not seem to generate much variability at all.
So most of the code inside the for loop is now being executed over and over again without making any actual changes.

Here is a concept that would give much higher performance. Ofcourse since I don't know the actual context of your code you will have to "fix it".

```
$carddetailsRepository = $this->get('oloy.carddetails.repository');
$cardexistencetype = ($key == "giftCardSchemeData") ? "Physical" : "E-Card";

foreach ($giftCardSchemeData as $keypreload => $preload) {
    $cardnumber = self::getCardNumber();    
    $carddetails = $carddetailsRepository->findByCardnumber($cardnumber);

    $giftCardSchemeDataDb = array('preload' => array('value' => 
    $preload['value'], 'expirymonths' => $preload['expiryMonths']));
    $otherdata = array('cardnumber' => $cardnumber, 'cardexistencetype' => 
    $cardexistencetype, 'isgiftcard' => true , 'giftcardamount' => 
    $preload['value'],'giftCardSchemeData' => 
    json_encode($giftCardSchemeDataDb), 'expirymonths' => 
    $preload['expiryMonths'], 'isloyaltycard' => false, 'loyaltypoints' => 
    null,'loyaltyCardSchemeData' => null, 'loyaltyRedeemAmount' => null, 
    'pinnumber' => 0);
    $output = array_merge($data, $otherdata);

    for ($i=0; $i <$preload['quantity'] ; $i++) {
      $cardid = new CarddetailsId($uuidGenerator->generate());
      $output['pinnumber'] = mt_rand(100000,999999);

        if (!$carddetails) {
          $commandBus->dispatch(
              new CreateCarddetails($cardid, $output)
          );
        } else {
          self::generateCardFunctionForErrorException($cardid, $output, $commandBus);
        }
    }
}
```

Also: if in this code you are triggering any database inserts or updates, you don't want to trigger them each iteration. You will want to start some kind of database transaction and flush the queries each X iterations instead.

Comment: Thanks for the optimization. instead of cron job Can symfony events dispatch and listener  take as much time as it needs for executing the loop?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. If you dispatch an event inside the loop, the listener executing code will still take as much time as it does right now.

Comment: What I am asking is when the controller file function called via the route we dispatch the above loop and return the success response. In here the event function will run or not in the background. the user can view the other pages when they return to that page if loop is finished we can show the response

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand what you mean. If this code runs the whole bunch, simply the page loading will take as lomg as it takes. The user won't get a response untill that time, unless you start using Big Pipe or something like that. So the user also has no menu and can't navigate to other pages untill this page has been loaded.

Comment: What you may want to do is: load this page just empty without all the giftcard logic, trigger a javascript event on that page that triggers the above code via a different route, which then returns an AJAX response. However, that is a whole other approach.

Comment: Sorry I can't explain it well. I don't know how to explain. Simply asking the events in symfony execute the script like cronjob in backend

Comment: As far as I'm concerned that is not how events work. You will have to use either a cronjob or an ajax trigger.

Comment: Okay man Thanks for looking into this I will try to use the cronjob

Comment: If you want to do some kind of async event, you should have a look at https://reactphp.org, or work with generators. Event dispatcher won't runs inside a different process.